# Not able to get response from httpclient, with get methord

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I am trying to get response through **get** method

I have to send 4 data (id , token , ROLE , EMPCODE) in header ,

I tryed to send it in two way

1st way >>>

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
    headers = headers.set('id', id).set('TOKEN', token).set('ROLE', role).set('EMPCODE' , employeeCode);
```

**With 1st way**

- I am getting **error**

> ERROR TypeError: "value is not iterable" 
>   ERROR TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
>          at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate

- also may be it is not hitting proper Url  in network I can see it is 
  hitting my route url http://localhost:2000/employee-details to fetch 
  data  and getting status 304

**2nd methord to send header**

```
  const headers  = new HttpHeaders();

   headers.append('TOKEN' , token);
   headers.append('id' , id);
   headers.append('ROLE' , role) ;
   headers.append('EMPCODE' , employeeCode);
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

- this way I am getting **403 invalid token**
 - when I checked in network header , http is hitting correct url , but
   Header appended is not passes

I am sharing code where I passes header with requesting to http.

```
 return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'employee/employee_details', {headers: headers});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tryed to send it in two way

Your first way should work. The error is most likely in other parts of the code. Maybe you are importing from the wrong npm package?

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmqyvt) showing that it does work.

Alternatively, you could also just define it as a normal JSON Object instead of explicitly instanciating the `HttpHeaders` like this:

```
let headers = { 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  id: id,
  TOKEN: token,
  ROLE: role,
  EMPCODE: employeeCode
};

return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/employee/employee_details', {headers: headers});
```

And another working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i4t2cz).

> also may be it is not hitting proper Url in network I can see it is hitting my route url http://localhost:2000/employee-details to fetch data and getting status 304

For that we need to see what your `this.baseUrl` contains. If you want it to go against `http://localhost:2000/employee-details`, it should be `http://localhost:2000/`